# Buying idea about a greenhouse

Tags: greenhouse

I want to buy a greenhouse. Then I started my fall planting program in the greenhouse. What else do I need to buy besides the greenhouse? I see some gardeners online who buy concrete, floors and water pipes...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: More details about your location and how cold it gets in winter would help.  What do you want to grow and will  you use the greenhouse all year or just for seedlings in winter and spring?

Comment: I have a floor of dry set house brick; has been excellent for 25 years. Any water spill is gone in a minute. It even supports an aquarium stand with 900 lb. load. Ventilation in sunny weather is critical.

Comment: Electric power for lights and heat is convenient.

Comment: What do you want to do with the greenhouse? Do you live in Alaska, Florida, Wyoming, the UK, or where? Different areas may require different things.

Answer (score 1):

What you buy depends on how you intend to set up and use the greenhouse.

If you have it set directly on dirt (or depending on construction of the greenhouse frame, on a concrete foundation with dirt inside it)and are planting in beds in the dirt, you obviously don't need floors, tables, or any of that sort of thing. If not, then you might.

There's an endless array of things other than the shell of the greenhouse you can spend money on, **depending what you are doing with the greenhouse and your climate.** Heating systems, irrigation systems, ventilation systems, cooling systems, trellising systems, etc, etc.

You might need none(*), or some, or all of those things - depending what you are doing with the greenhouse and in what climate.

*generally you will at minimum need a vent system of some sort so the greenhouse does not overheat and cook your plants on sunny days. On the low end or for small home-garden greenhouses, the wax cylinder automatic vent openers are common/typical. Depending on remembering to open and close windows manually usually fails someday when you forget to, or are away.

*i.e.* there's a huge difference between what you need for a greenhouse conservatory to show off in the architectural magazine spread and an Eliot Coleman style unheated hoop house to extend seasons. The latter you'll probably have coldframes and fabric tunnels inside, the former never would. The former would have heating, might have cooling, would have lighting, etc...and there are many other uses for a greenhouse, with the associated needs/wants for stuff to make that either possible or easier.